# Creating multiple user roles in Rails App with single login (Rails Devise, Pundit, STI? HELP)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I am currently a Rails noob, and I've been trying my best to map out the data models for this specific Rails App. I am trying to build an business Employee/Customer App where there are three types of users (Admin, Employee, and Customer).

The Admin will have full control where he/she can add/edit new Employees and Customers (which will in turn create user accounts for them). Employees will be able to view their own account details, and customers the same.

How can I set this up with Rails devise and pundit? I've lurked all over Google and stackoverflow and the most common solution seems to revolve around having one User model and using STI/pundit to set roles for users and restrict access to specific views. Can someone help break this down for me before I go crazy?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, if a role is exclusive (meaning an Employee can't be an Admin or Customer, Customer can't be Admin/Employee, etc.) you'd put a `role:integer` column on your `User`s model that is Rails enum:

`enum role: %i[customer employee admin]`

This gets you what you need for different authorization (what a user can access) either via your own custom code or something like [pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit).

If your use case needs a Role to have different data, you can do Single Table Inheritance with the Users table, though I strongly recommend avoiding STI.

If your users need more than one role AND you need different data/behavior for each role, you might consider a polymorphic association. I wrote an answer about that previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327546/design-pattern-for-person-with-multiple-roles/47330567#47330567).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! In my case, different roles do need to have different data (such as Customers needing payment info and address). I've already implemented STI into my app. Is there any specific reason why you strongly recommend me to not use it?

Comment: My experience with STI has been very unpleasant every time. With 1:1 model:table, the data structure tends to be the simplest possible relational structure. With STI, models and tables bloat fast and you end up with a lot of empty data and complex model logic, even if you're doing proper OOP. Lastly, there seems to always come a time where two related STI models need slightly different behavior for the same column, which complicates it further and reduces predictability. Sometimes it's the best choice we have, so if you must, take care to keep your behaviors as separate as possible.